# User interactions with Python's Flask

Tags: python, flask, bots, slack

I have a question about Python: in Flask, I know how to create buttons with the options `yes` and `no`, but I don't know how the user can interact with them by Slack, and how when clicking those buttons, depending on the answer the user has clicked on, an answer or another can be displayed on a Slack channel. I have this code:

```
'''
    It creates an app using slack_bot.py
'''

import os
import json
from flask import Flask, current_app, request, make_response, Response, render_template
from slackclient import SlackClient, process
import slack_bot as sb

# Your app's Slack bot user token
SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = sb.get_token()
SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN = os.environ.get("SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN")

# Slack client for Web API requests
SLACK_CLIENT = SlackClient(SLACK_BOT_TOKEN)

# Flask webserver for incoming traffic from Slack
APP = Flask(__name__)


def verify_slack_token(request_token):
    '''Verify token to not get it stealed from others'''
    if SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN != request_token:
        print("Error: invalid verification token!!!")
        print("Received {} but was expecting {}".format(request_token, SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN))
    return make_response("Request contains invalid Slack verification token", 403)


OPTIONS = [
    {
        "text": "Sí",
        "value": "si"
    },
    {
        "text": "No",
        "value": "no"
    }
]


MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS = [
    {
        "fallback": "Upgrade your Slack client to use messages like these.",
        "callback_id": "Confirm_button",
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "Sí",
                "text": "Sí",
                "value": "si",
                "type": "button"
            },
            {
                "name": "No",
                "text": "No",
                "value": "no",
                "type": "button"
            }
        ]
    }
]


@APP.route("/slack/message_options", methods=["POST"])
def message_options():
    ''' Parse the request payload'''
    form_json = json.loads(request.form["payload"])
    verify_slack_token(form_json["token"])

    # Dictionary of menu options which will be sent as JSON
    menu_options = {
        "options": [
            {
                "text": "Sí",
                "value": "si"
            },
            {
                "text": "No",
                "value": "no"
            }
        ]
    }

    # Load options dict as JSON and respond to Slack
    return Response(json.dumps(menu_options), mimetype='application/json')


@APP.route("/slack/message_actions", methods=["POST"])
def message_actions():

    '''
        Sends the report question
    '''

    form_json = json.loads(request.form["payload"])
    verify_slack_token(form_json["token"])
    message_text = "Voleu enviar l\'informe??"

    selection = form_json["actions"][0]["selected_options"][0]["value"]
    if selection == "Sí":
        message_text = "Operació acceptada."
    else:
        message_text = "Operació cancel·lada."
    response = SLACK_CLIENT.api_call(
        "chat.update",
        channel=form_json["channel"]["id"],
        ts=form_json["message_ts"],
        text=message_text,
        response_type="in_channel",
        options=OPTIONS
    )

    return make_response(response, 200)


with APP.app_context():
    # within this block, current_app points to app.
    print(current_app.name)


SLACK_CLIENT.api_call(
    "chat.postMessage",
    channel="#lufranxucybots",
    text="Voleu enviar l\'informe??",
    attachments=MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS,
    response_type="in_channel"
)


@APP.route('/')
@APP.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    '''Index'''
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html")

    if request.form["submit"] == "submit":
        yes = request.form["Sí"]
        no = request.form["No"]
        success = process(yes, no)

        return render_template("index.html", fooResponse="Successful" if success else "Failed")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.run(debug=True)
```

where `slack_bot.py` is:

```
'''
    Log bot: to send by Slack the error logs which are usually
    sent by command prompt.
'''

from slackclient import SlackClient

import constants as c
import utilities as u

log = u.ulog.set_logger(__file__)


def get_token():
    """ Retrives slack token """

    try:
        with open(c.SLACK_TOKEN, "r") as file:
            return file.read()

    except IOError as e:
        log.error("Token not found", error=e)
        return None


def send_message(text, channel="#test"):
    """
        Send message to Slack

        Args:
            text:       what will be sent
            channel:    where it will be posted
    """

    token = get_token()
    slack_client = SlackClient(token)

    slack_client.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel=channel,
        text=text
    )



if __name__ == '__main__':
    TEXT = input("Write your text: ")
    send_message(TEXT)
```

I have this template, is it correct??:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/" method="post">
    CHIPS:<br />
    <input type="text" name="Sí"><br />
    SNACKS:<br />
    <input type="text" name="No"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

{% if fooResponse is not none %}
    {{ fooResponse }}
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

P.D.: pylint does not recognise `process` in any module, which module is it from??

Well... The main question I wanna make about all this is: how the heck do I make code to not just send unworking `yes`and `no` buttons, but also to make them work due to the interaction an user, and moreover to print slack messages when the user interacts?? Is any line of the first code or of the template badly coded?? (trust me, `slack_bot.py` is well coded).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to send the question to slack in its API's desired format: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons

Comment: Yes... but what I wanna mean, is that if I click any of the responses, the buttons get frozen for a second and then they return to the status as I didn't click them!!! And worst of all: no answer. I have seen the page you have redirected me to, but I can't see the issue... The main question is: how do I do to keep the clicked button held, and how to make it return a string, for instance, if I click yes, I wanna be returned "Accepted operation"?? I know I have to insert that string in attachment answers, but how??

Comment: I've just tried with `response_url`, but I keep in the same situation... What fails here?? I have been trying to fix this error for days, but there's no effect!!!